# Create API endpoints from Database instance Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I'm currently working in a project and to summarize my problem; I need to monitor several processes, knowing that for a process to be initiated you need some configuration.
So to make stuff more clear:

1. You go to a link to create a process.
2. Once you create the process, it starts running. A link for that process gets created.
3. If you go to that link(newly created) you could monitor or communicate with that process.

Any ideas on how to implement this with Flask+multiprocessing+Sql, or maybe another web framework like django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought is that this is *not* going to scale well. Having a new process spawned for every single user interaction could balloon into something crazy.

You also may run into some synchronization issues with your DB, depending on if these independent instances modify shared tables/resources/whatever.

That being said, I have a slightly similar (and admittedly pretty bad example) of a flask app I have that controls a light strip. The reason I bring it up is that it is a flask app, and it spawns a child process that runs a task, and then there is a status endpoint that queries the status of the process (communicate). There's not database/persistence layer but it's similar enough.

Maybe something like this? https://github.com/Vizzyy/Lights/blob/master/app.py

Then you could create a temporary table for each spawned process, and that way the process only communicates with its table and no need for a lock.

Comment: thanks, the scaling part , especially the user interaction is accounted for. Your answer is helpful, will try implementing it.